# can I start sql id autoincrement from 0001 ???? 4 digit number

Tags: mysql, sql

For example:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | Tomy |
| 0002 | Jerry |

Comment: Sounds like you want to set the `ZEROFILL` for that column to `4`. This changes the _representation_ of the numbers, but they'll always be stored as their plain number in data (`1`, `17`, `369`, etc).

Comment: You're usually better off handling this on the app that's *accessing* MySQL.